# Match fourth character of string(phone number) using regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to check whether the fourth character for the string(phone number) is among 7,8,9 or not.How can i do that using regular expression?Below is sample phone number  to check.

```
+9198714356
```

Comment: You can do it using string functions easily

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: have a play at https://regex101.com/

Comment: `"789".indexOf(str.charAt(3)) >= 0`

Comment: I want using regex only.I know i can match first character using `^[789]` but i want to match fourth character

Comment: @Bhuvi You would use `^.{3}[789]` to look at other characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\+\d{2}[789]\d{9}
```

https://regex101.com/r/HM01ug/4

Comment: I think by 4 th character he mean 1 to 4 not 0 to 4

Comment: And its precisely what I have done. +1234567890 -- we don't count "+" since it's not digit, so 1,2,3 and 4th position it's 4 so \d{3}[789] mean 7,8 or 9 on 4th position

Comment: +91**9**8714356 ..its index 3 .. i checked your reg ex link its checking for index 4 .. kindly verify

Comment: I want to match only the fourth char of string..Like in +9198714356 i want to match only the digit after "+91".

Comment: Next time you have to be more specific, if You want to count "+" or don't. Logic says that we NEVER count + but... Edits have been made.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nDz5J1/1 I don't see it matching this number you gave above

Answer (score 0):

hope this works for you

```
\+\d{2}[789]\d{9}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.